# How to add Mavericks Message into trusted devices in Facebook?

Tags: macos, messages, facebook

One-liner: I've enabled SMS notice for new devices Login, and I got spammed every time I wake my Mac.

Facebook seemed to log devices accessing your account, users will be prompted about remembering that device with the named entered. But when Message logs in Facebook Chat, looks like it ignores that device registering step and go right through.

I want to know if I can log into Facebook somewhere to add the Message app as a known device, or some settings in the Message app that can prevent this issue...

Spamming myself just feels so dumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can generate an application specific password in security settings and type that in instead of your password. This is will ensure it works without pinging you again and again for the code.

Comment: Never knew Facebook has app specific passwords too, thanks.